# Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:10000

Tags: cloudera, hue

On Cloudera

```
Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:10000',)
```

is gotten and still exists when having issued:

```
sudo service hive-server2 restart
```

and status subsequently states it is running.

happens not all the time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

fixed it

quickstart vms!!!

Comment: I never use cloudera express now, it screws things up